sshuttle ssh_packet_write_poll error on pfsense
I’m trying to use sshuttle on pFsense CE OS and when I execute sshuttle -r *my_actual_username*@*my_actual_host* 0.0.0.0/0, following error shows up:
client_loop: ssh_packet_write_poll: Connection to *my_actual_server*: Permission denied
However, everything else like ssh scp ssh-copy-id seems to work without any problems. I searched the internet and didn’t even find anything related to ssh_packet_write_poll. is the origin of this error from server or client? I’m open to any suggestions.
